# How to know a string array is empty in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba

I dim a empty array of string, but how can I get whether the array is empty? I have tried below but get no idea.

```
Sub arrtest()
  Dim myVar() As String
  Debug.Print VarType(myVar)   '8200
  Debug.Print TypeName(myVar)  'String()
  Debug.Print IsEmpty(myVar)   'False
  Debug.Print IsNull(myVar)    'False
  Debug.Print LBound(myVar)    'Error
  Debug.Print UBound(myVar)    'Error
  Debug.Print myVar Is Nothing 'Error
End Sub
```

Comment: easiest way -> if not myVar then msgBox "not initialised"

Answer (score 7):

Here are two options

If you're checking if the array's been initialized

```
If (Not myVar) = -1 Then
    'Array has been initialized
End if
```

If you're checking whether or not it has values. **Note:** This only works for String Arrays

```
If Len(Join(myVar)) > 0 Then
    'Array contains values
End if
```

Comment: You sir saved my life today with this answer.